# how to restore np.arry from np.array string in pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy-ndarray

how to restore np.arry from  np.array string in pandas?

np.arry is stored in a dataframe df,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'X':['[2 5 6]','[5 6 9]']})
>>> df
         X
0  [2 5 6]
1  [5 6 9]
```

how can I restore the np.array and get the following

```
   [[2 5 6],
     [5 6 9]]
```

Comment: just get the values `df.values`

Comment: >>> df.X.values   only got a list of string
array(['[2 5 6]', '[5 6 9]'], dtype=object) , not [[2 5 6], [5 6 9]]

Comment: you said you wanted a reference the the numpy array.  if you want a reference to the list `df.values.tolist()`.   actually you are really saying you want the list in column X `df["X"].values.tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.array([line for line in df['X'].map(lambda x: x.replace(']','').replace('[','').split(' '))]).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
df.X.str.replace(r'\s', r', ', regex=True).apply(literal_eval).tolist()
# [[2, 5, 6], 
#  [5, 6, 9]]
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':['[2 5 6]','[5 6 9]']})
```